# TortoiseHG: Abort: authorization failed - blocking?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, kiln, fogbugz-on-demand

I'm currently facing an issue with respect to connecting to a repo through kiln. 
I have two machines on the same network, one is running Windows Server 2016, the other is running Windows 10.

Both machines are running TortoiseHg 4.3.1 and Mercurial 4.3.1.

The Windows Server machine seems to be able to clone a repo just fine

```
hg clone https://<NAME.KILNHG>/Code/Repositories/Group/Test
```

I get prompted for a username/password, which is fine, and the repo manages to clone to the machine

However, when trying the exact thing on the Windows 10 machine, I receive the error "abort: authorization failed"

```
hg clone --debug --traceback https://<NAME.KILNHG>/Code/Repositories/Group/Test
using https://<NAME.KILNHG>/Code/Repositories/Group/Test
sending capabilities command
using auth.kiln.* for authentication
using auth.kiln.* for authentication
http authorization required for https://<NAME.KILNHG>/Code/Repositories/Group/Test
realm: kiln
user: MyUserName
password:
http auth: user MyUserName, password ********
using auth.kiln.* for authentication
http auth: user MyUserName, password ********
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\scmutil.pyo", line 150, in callcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 292, in _runcatchfunc
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 896, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 658, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 904, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 893, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1077, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1410, in clone
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 483, in clone
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 178, in peer
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 153, in _peerorrepo
  File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 391, in instance
  File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 123, in _fetchcaps
  File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 301, in _call
  File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 233, in _callstream
Abort: authorization failed
abort: authorization failed
```

I'm not sure what *could* be blocking this at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.